# Using 'Model' classes as domain entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, entity-framework-5, code-first

I recently followed this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) which demonstrates well how to create a simple ASP.NET MVC 4 application that modifies the contents of a database using EF5 code first. I have 2 questions:

1. In the completed solution, there are no mapping or domain classes for the entities. Is EF effectively using the Model classes to generate these automatically? If so, are there any disadvantages to this approach?
2. Is it possible to achieve something similar using nHibernate? I.e. is it possible / recommended to use the same class that is passed to the view as the model for generating DB schemas etc.? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that this tutorial aims to provide you with the fastest way to get things done using MVC4 & EF5. In that case, EF will use [Convention.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962) to create the DB, set relationships between tables, set primary keys, ... And that's why there's no mapping classes at all.
In this tutorial, your EF entities are used as domain classes and view models. It's obviously not the best way to respect [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [SOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principles. But sometimes, it might fit your needs!

It's always a best thing to keep in mind the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle and avoid putting to much abstraction and layers in your application for the sake of it. If your application is OK like this than it's fine. And when it will be required to separate things in different layers, for any business needs, refactoring will help you out!

EF offers 2 other ways to map your entities to DB objects, [Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583) and the [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617). Annotations are cool because attributes are shared with MVC to enable client validation but it has some limitations, that's where the Fluent API helps.

What I would recommand at the end, is to keep it simple. On big applications it might be easier to have a separate view model and map it to your domain entities returned by your business services in a model builder layer. But on small applications that are not supposed to change often, why not using the same entities both for view model and domain, as in the tutorial?

Here's a [link to a recent EF training](https://techblog.betclicgroup.com/2013/10/08/entity-framework-training/) I've made, you might find some useful information to go further.